# Does AWS EC2 instance re-start automatically if it stops due to exceeding quota?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using Ubuntu on Amazon EC2.  If an EC2 instance stops running due to a monthly usage quota being exceeded (i.e., too many requests), does it start up automatically on the first of the next month or would one have to manually re-boot it?

Comment: No, it does not start. You can create Cloudwatch Event cron rule to start it automatically each month.

Comment: I can't think of any 'quota' that would cause an Amazon EC2 instance to be stopped. It will only stop if there is a specific API call, or if it is part of an Auto Scaling group.